# Params only running the first time I click

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

The params of my categories are only running the first click.

I have this structure:

[image]

I have 2 categories: category/sell and category/rent

sell and rent are the params

When I click on a category it works.

But it only runs on the first click, so when I click on the other category svelte doesn't rerender.

My code [catName].svelte:

```js
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    const catName = $page.params.catName;
    // $: catName = $page.params.catName;
    $: listings = [];
</script>
```

Comment: Please simplify your code to a minimal example, you might even fix the problem in the process...

Comment: Does it not work with the reactive statement (the one that's commented out)?

Comment: The component does not get recreated if the component of the route does not change => You need the commented out reactive statement because only the page store is updated.

Comment: If I use ```$: catName = $page.params.catName;``` I get an error, the list is not fechted.

Comment: Then you delete the code with the actual problem, because this code has no problems when using the reactive statement.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the deleted code, the issue is that your data fetching routine (`fetchListings`) is not reactive and is not dependent on the category name. Hence, it will only run *once* in the lifetime of your page component.

Essentially, you will want to have a statement such as:

```js
$: fetchListings(catName)
```

so that you run your data fetching routine whenever `catName` is updated.

I have put together a bare-bones example for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-param-example?file=src%2Froutes%2Fcategory%2F%5Bcategory%5D.svelte) (data is not fetched, merely read from hardcoded values for the sake of simplicity, but the concept remains the same).

**Note**: that's in addition to making `catName` itself reactive, obviously, as stated in the comments to your question:

```js
$: catName = $page.params.catName
```

Comment: When I do this ```listings = listings[cat];``` the code crashes.

Comment: You do realize both the variable you are making the assignment to and the array you're assigning from have the same name? Of course that will not work... Change one of these two variables to another name.

Comment: I will try to not be stupid :)